# binary '==': no operator found which takes a left - hand operand of type 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>'

Tags: c++

This error is pretty common but none of the solutions I have seen worked for me.

The solutions I have seen were with other types of operands instead of pair but that shouldn't be an excuse.

What I understand in the error is that I have not defined the equal operator with pairs, but I am not comparing pairs at any moment, I am always working with the key or the value.

```
#include "cabezeras.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x;
    ifstream inFile;
    bool t2, t3;
    int times2 = 0, times3 = 0;
    map<char, int> mymap;
    map<char, int>::iterator it;
    pair<char, int> aux_pair;

    inFile.open("C:/Users/victor/source/repos/AdventOfCode2018/Day2/input.txt");
    if (!inFile) {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        exit(1);
    }
    while (getline(inFile, x)) {
        t2 = false, t3 = false;
        mymap.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
            it = find(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), x[i]);
            if (it == mymap.end()) {
                aux_pair = make_pair(x[i], 1);
                mymap.insert(aux_pair);
            }
            else {
                it->second++;
            }
        }

        it = mymap.begin();
        int valor;
        while (it != mymap.end()) {
            if (valor == 2) {
                t2 = true;
            }

            if (valor == 3) {
                t3 = true;
            }

            it++;
        }

        if (t2) {
            times2++;
        }
        if (t3) {
            times3++;
        }
    }

    inFile.close();

    cout << "Val = " << times2 * times3 << endl;
}
```

When debbuging(it takes me to xutility file):

```
template<class _InIt, class _Ty> inline
_InIt _Find_unchecked1(_InIt _First, const _InIt _Last, const _Ty& _Val, false_type)
{   // find first matching _Val
    for (; _First != _Last; ++_First)
        if (*_First == _Val) // THIS IS THE LINE OF THE ERROR
            break;
    return (_First);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why the use of `aux_pair` and explicit `insert` call? Why not just us `mymap[x[i]] = 1`? Or better yet skip the `find` call and only use [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert). If the key exists you will get a `pair` containing an iterator to the element (which you can then use for the increment) and a bool indicator if the element was inserted or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `std::find` you should be using `std::map::find`, so replace this

```
it = find(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), x[i]);
```

with

```
it = mymap.find(x[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You still have lots of C habits, forget about them.

The map iterator has a `const` for its first member, that's what the error message is telling you:

```
auto it = mymap.find(x[i]);
```

or if you don't have C++11

```
map<const char, int>::iterator it = mymap.find(x[i]);
```

But don't declare all your variables at the beginning, loose this habit, declare them where you need them at the appropriate scope.

When you need another `it` after, use another `auto`, and probably worth changing the name for something more descriptive.

But as Slava said, the default initializer for `map` says, you can do:

```
for (char c : x ) ++mymap[c];
```

Answer (score 1):

You way over-complicated your code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
        it = find(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), x[i]);
        if (it == mymap.end()) {
            aux_pair = make_pair(x[i], 1);
            mymap.insert(aux_pair);
        }
        else {
            it->second++;
        }
    }
```

should be instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) 
    mymap[ x[i] ]++;
```

or even shorter using for range loop:

```
for (char c : x ) mymap[c]++;
```

[`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) is specially designed for cases like this and you can find it in example code of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that option is easier than mine and I should use it in the future. In this particular case, I think I would have to check first if that character exist in the map and then increment it or add it.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code:

```
it = find(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), x[i]);
if (it == mymap.end()) {
    aux_pair = make_pair(x[i], 1);
    mymap.insert(aux_pair);
}
else {
    it->second++;
}
```

Could be replaced by

```
auto insert_pair = mymap.insert({x[i], 0});
++*insert_pair.first->second;
```

The [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) function returns a `std::pair` with an iterator as the `first` value and a boolean indicator as the `second`.

If the insertion failed, because the key `x[i]` already exists, the iterator in `first` will be an iterator to the existing element pair. If the insertion succeeded, then the `first` will be an iterator to the newly inserted element pair.

Since I insert the data value `0`, if the insertion was successful then increasing the value will make it `1` (which is what you insert). And if it fails because the key already exist, then we increase the existing value (like you do).